# DriveApp .addViewer() .addEditor() internal folder files not inheriting permissions

Tags: google-apps-script

I am having an issue with DriveApp files nested in folders not inheriting folder permissions after I change from edit to view permissions. The steps are as follows:

Add a folder (containing internal files) with "edit" permissions to another user's drive via:

```
userFolder.addFolder(folderToShare);
folderToShare.addEditor(user);
```

...then add the folder again, this time changing "edit" to "view" permissions:

```
userFolder.addFolder(folderToShare);
folderToShare.addViewer(user);
```

The internal files in "folder" should change permissions based on the permissions of the parent folder. The user should inherit "view" permissions on files in the folder when "folder" is changed to the "view" permission for the user. However, if the user has "edit" permission on the files in "folder" when folder.addViewer(user) is called, the folder gets "view" permissions, but the files in folder remain with the "edit" permissions for the user unchanged.

```
var folderToShare = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
var userFolders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(thisUser[1]);
if (userFolders.hasNext() == false) {
  // do something
} else var userFolder = userFolders.next(); 
userFolder.addFolder(folderToShare);
folderToShare.addEditor(thisUser[1]);  
// folder and files in folder get edit permission
// trying the following on the folder results in view permission on the folder, but edit permission remains on the folder's files
userFolder.addFolder(folderToShare);            
folderToShare.addViewer(thisUser[1]);
```

I have tried .removeEditor(user) before using .addViewer(user), but to no avail. Do I have to calll folderToShare.getFiles() and iterate to change permission for each individual file or am I missing something?

Comment: have your tried to .revokePermissions(user) ?

Comment: Yep. That doesn't seem to work either. Worse yet, when a user adds a file to the folder, it is by default editable...not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I used Utilities.sleep(5000) as a starting point after the .removeEditor() and before completing the .addViewer() function and that seemed to do the trick! It just needs a millisecond or two to complete the removal of the editor before adding the viewer.﻿ I will try to hone in on a sweetspot for a time interval.

Here is the final code:

```
if (sharingPermissions == 'edit' || sharingPermissions == 'submit') {
      userFolder.addFolder(folderToShare);
      folderToShare.addEditor(thisUser[1]); 
    } else if (sharingPermissions == 'view') {         
        try {folderToShare.removeEditor(thisUser[1]);}
        catch (error) {}
        Utilities.sleep(5000);
        userFolder.addFolder(folderToShare); 
        folderToShare.addViewer(thisUser[1]);
      }
```

Seems to work fine now...